# what does this perl -ane mean in the find command of shell script?

Tags: shell, perl

I have this find script

```
Find $DATA/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 |\
perl -ane ' s:.*/((.+)\-[0-9]{8,10}[a-z]*([_\-].*)?):$2: && print; ' | \
sort -u > $loctmp/speakers_all.txt
```

can any shell script god decode this for me?
what is the perl -ane command doing?

Comment: As for what that "inline script" (everything between `' '`) does, it runs a regular expression which matches a certain pattern in the line and replaces it by a part of it; so it rewrites the line.  Then that's printed and all such lines sent to sort.

Comment: Note that nothing here justify to use perl in particular. Since all quantifiers are greedy, you will obtain the same result faster using `sed -nE 's#.*/(.+)-[0-9]{8,10}[a-z]*([_-].*)?#\1#p'`

Answer (score 3):

`perl -n` says "Iterate over the input lines, but don't print them."

`perl -a` means to break apart the input lines like in awk, but it doesn't look like it's necessary here.

`perl -e` says "This argument is the program to run".

Run `perldoc perlrun` to read more about Perl's command-line usage.

Comment: Docs also available [online](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun)

Comment: Thank you so much @andy isr

Comment: Re "*I don't think [`-a`] is necessary here*", Correct. It populates `@F`, which isn't used by the program. /// Re "*Iterate over the input lines*", More clearly: Execute the program for each line of input. (The line is found in `$_`.)

Comment: We can see exactly what perl is going to do my adding `-MO=Deparse` to the options: `perl -MO=Deparse -ane ' s:.*/((.+)\-[0-9]{8,10}[a-z]*([_\-].*)?):$2: && print; '` spits out the code perl will run.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ane ' s:.*/((.+)\-[0-9]{8,10}[a-z]*([_\-].*)?):$2: && print; '
```

The command switches for Perl, as found in `perl -h`:

```
-a                autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into @F)
-n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
```

Autosplit is not used, and can be safely removed.

`-e` is just to denote where the code to run is. Can also be replaced with a file that contains the code. E.g. `perl foo.pl`.

The code itself is just a regex substitution. If expanded, the code looks like this:

```
while (<>) {
    s:.*/((.+)\-[0-9]{8,10}[a-z]*([_\-].*)?):$2: && print; 
}
```

- `while (<>)` loops over the input, putting each line into `$_`, the default variable.
- `s:...` is the substitution operator, but the default delimiters `/` have been replaced with colons `:`. Typically this is done to avoid having to escape delimiters inside the regex.
- The regex itself matches any character `.`, 0 or more times `*`, followed by a slash `/` (presumably the reason for the changed delimiter). Then a string made up of any character 1 or more times `.+`, which is captured `()`. Then a dash `\-` followed by 8 to 10 digits 0-9, followed by characters a-z 0 or more times. Then it captures a string made up of either `_` or `-`, followed by any character `.` 0 or more times. This capture is also made optional by `?`, meaning it can match 0 or 1 time. If there is a match, it will be replaced by whatever is captured in `$2`. The capture `$2` is the first part, before the slash `(.+)`, as near as I can tell.
- `&&` means only execute the RHS if the LHS is true. I.e. only print if the regex matches.
- `print` is the same as `print $_`.

In short, the code will extract the part between the last slash, and the 8 to 10 digits, and discard everything else in the string. With the exception of the optional match, which means that a string after 8-10 digits can be kept, if it has underscore or dash at the beginning. Then print.

Comment: *"and discard everything else in the string"*, not always. The end of the string remains if there are no underscore or hyphen after the digits and the eventual letters. `([_-].*)?` is optional.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That is true. It's a weird regex, wonder if that part is intentional.